# How to get metadata about a application using appstream API?

Tags: package-management, pacman, appstream

I am trying to make a GUI front-end to `pacman` using `alpm`. I recently found out that `appstream` can help me fetch icons, screenshots and all for a application. But I don't understand how do I do that. In the documentation for `appstream` there is `struct` `AsIcon` which defines information about a icon, like filename, url, size and all, but it has nothing like `get_icon_for_app("app_name")`. Please if someone can point me in the right direction it would be a great help. Some example code or something.

Answer (score 0):

I started making progress on figuring this out, so I thought I would document it with a code snippet. Hopefully this will be helpful to people looking up this question.

```
//Create a new "pool" of metadata:
AsPool * pool = as_pool_new();

//Set the pool flags. In this case,
//I'm choosing the flag that tells it
//to load the Flatpak metadata from the standard location:
as_pool_set_flags(pool, AS_POOL_FLAG_LOAD_FLATPAK);

//Load the metadata.
//I'm supposed to pass objects for handling
//errors and cancellations, but I don't care
//right now and NULL works.
as_pool_load(pool, NULL, NULL);

//I'm getting a single component (read: app) by id,
//but it returns an array because there could be
//multiple repos with the same app, and if so it
//will return one component for each of them:
GPtrArray * components = as_pool_get_components_by_id(pool, "refname");
```

So that gives me a metadata pool and a component (app). From here I can use the methods to install, remove, get metadata, or whatever else I want. I think this can be a good starting point for interacting with the AppStream API.